# When I export my Java game with embedded JRE the game can not more read Cyrillic strings from external files

Tags: java, gradle, character-encoding, javapackager

I try to export my videogame as executable with an embedded Java.
When I launch the videogame from the IDE (Intellij IDEa) it works normally with external Cyrillic text files. But when I export it - It can not more read Cyrillic data files.

My Gradle build script:

```
task packageMyApp(type: io.github.fvarrui.javapackager.gradle.PackageTask, dependsOn: build) {        
    mainClass = mainClassName
    bundleJre = true
    generateInstaller = false
    administratorRequired = false
    platform = "windows"        
}
```

What can be wrong? Should I manual change the JRE which will be integrated in the game build?
I have also tried to use JPackage. After creation of the executable distribution I have the same trouble.
[image]

Comment: "It can not more read Cyrillic data files." How exactly? Is there an exception of some sort? In which way the problem manifests itself?

Comment: No, it opens the files and reads the strings. But the content is not readable. Only hieroglyphs

Comment: *But when I export it - It can not more read Cyrillic data files.* The more important thing is *how (and where) it's run*. What's the answer to that?

Comment: What is the embedded JRE version? What is the encoding of the data files?

Comment: The files have UTF-8 encoding and working without problems inside the IDE. If I right understood it uses by default: liberica-17.0.6

Comment: @g00se I test on the same Windows PC. Inside the IDE it works perfect by after I create the executable package - it can not more read Cyrillic characters. What are you talking about when you says: how it run?

Comment: *What are you talking about when you says: how it run?* I mean - is it a jar, .exe or what? If the former, how do you start it?

Comment: Also, is this text being displayed in a *windowed* or console fashion?

Comment: @g00se It is .exe. I launch it using simple double click on Windows x64 machine. The JRE is integrated and lays in the same folder as the .EXE

Comment: For example: I have created an another executable with the same Gradle-settings/script using my LibGDX game. I have not got any errors - everything is fine. But this game (created using Processing) can not determine Cyrillic characters after export. I have tried already the third packaging tool (launch4j, JPackage and JavaPackager). My text displayed on a window.

Comment: I'm wondering if your wrapper is expecting embedded fonts that are missing (i.e. one(s) that will do Cyrillic)

Comment: @g00se The hardcoded strings are shown normally. But the strings which were uploaded from an external file can not be right "decoded".

Comment: OK. Moving theories ;) Here's the next one: the vm is getting invoked with the platform value of `file.encoding` which was somehow different in your IDE. If this theory is correct `echo 'System.getProperty("file.encoding");' | jshell` would say something other than a Unicode encoding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When reading your data files, make sure that you are specifying the encoding in which to read the files. If you use methods that could take an encoding but do not specify one, then up to Java 17 the system default encoding is used, which can be `UTF-8` but can also be something else. It might be the case that when launching through the IDE the system encoding is overwritten to be `UTF-8` and that it works due to that.